# How to get custom claims for IdentityServer4 Itself

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am running IdentityServer4 hosted in an MVC application similar to https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity/src/IdentityServerAspNetIdentity.

This IdentityServer host exposes a ProfileService like such near the bottom of the ConfigureServices method.

`services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();`

From all of the examples and QuickStarts I have looked at, I am not seeing where the IdentityServer MVC host itself can access profile data. Meaning the IDServ MVC host is a client of itself and can access claim data. I have seen examples where IDServ adds OpenIdConnect as an external provider but it seems off that the MVC app would list itself as the external provider so that I can get ProfileService claim data.

My Startup.cs (of the Host IDServ MVC App) looks like this

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        HostingEnvironment = env;
    }

    ... removed for brevity


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name; 
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("connString");

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        // configures IIS out-of-proc settings (see https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14882)
        services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
        {
            iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
            iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
        });

        // configures IIS in-proc settings
        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(iis =>
        {
            iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
            iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
        });


        services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(b =>
         b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
             sqlOptions =>
             {
                 sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(AuthDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name);
                 sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), null);
             })
        ); 

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>()
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        })
        .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        })
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
        })
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddSigningAuthority(HostingEnvironment, Configuration)
        .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies");

        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

        services.AddTransient<AzureTableStorageLoggerMiddleware>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<AzureTableStorageLoggerMiddleware>();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        loggerFactory.AddTableStorage(env.EnvironmentName + "Auth", Configuration["AzureStorageConnectionString"], accessor);
        app.UseMiddleware<AzureTableStorageLoggerMiddleware>(); 

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute(); 
        });
    }       

}
```

As you can see above, I am not using .AddOpenIdConnect on itself and  am wondering whether I need to add it on the host itself so that I can obtain the profile service claim data on the host IDServ app like such...

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
   options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
   options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
   options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
   options.Authority = "https://localhost:44378/"; //seems silly to have it point to it's own host
   options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
   options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
   options.ClientId = "idserv";
   options.ClientSecret = "<<>>";
   options.ResponseType = "code id_token token";
   options.SaveTokens = true;
 });
```

On the bright side, a completely separate MVC Client does obtain the ProfileService claim data when using the .AddOpenIdConnect() middleware approach, just not the host.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As IdentityServer's documentation said:

> You can provide a callback to transform the claims of the incoming token after validation. Either use the helper method, e.g.:

```cs
    services.AddLocalApiAuthentication(principal =>
    {
        principal.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim("additional_claim", "additional_value"));
    
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    });
```

you can read complete guide in [Claims Transformation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html#claims-transformation)

2. You can write a new MiddleWare and load user claims.

```cs
    public class ClaimsMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public ClaimsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            if (httpContext.User != null && httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var sub = httpContext.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Subject);
                if (sub != null)
                {
                    var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(sub.Value);

                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        var claims = //fill this variable in your way;

                        var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
                        httpContext.User.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                    }
                }

                await _next(httpContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

and call it in your Startup.cs

```cs
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseMiddleware<ClaimsMiddleware>();
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there no way to accomplish the same outcome solely in the IDServ host Startup.cs file?

Comment: Yes, there is, you can add your calims in the Startup.cs file when you are adding localApiAuthentication *services.AddLocalApiAuthentication*. you can find complete guide in [Claims Transformation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html#claims-transformation).

Comment: The middleware approach works better for me so that I can access the userManager via the DI. Thank you Mehrdad